# Get last item name on the shelf

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE stock (shelf varchar, item_id INT, item_name varchar);
```

Now I want to get a list of last items on each shelf. Last item is the item with the largest `item_id`. I know how to get only the last id:

```
SELECT shelf, MAX(item_id) FROM stock GROUP BY shelf;
```

Given this data:

```
INSERT INTO stock (shelf, item_id, item_name) VALUES (1, 1, 'one');
INSERT INTO stock (shelf, item_id, item_name) VALUES (2, 2, 'two');
INSERT INTO stock (shelf, item_id, item_name) VALUES (1, 3, 'three');
INSERT INTO stock (shelf, item_id, item_name) VALUES (2, 4, 'four');
```

The code above returns this:

```
 2     |   4
 1     |   3
```

But how do I get the last item's name as well?

*(It is better to have a solution for the standard SQL, but if that is not possible right now I am using Postgres.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `Generic` solution using `Correlated sub-query`works in every database engine I know

```
select * from stock s
where item_id = (SELECT  MAX(item_id) FROM stock s1 where s1.shelf = s.shelf)
```

Another way is using `ROW_NUMBER` which is efficient than `correlated sub-query` approach but does not work with all `RDBMS` ex : `Mysql`

Answer (score 1):

Use SUB query. This will work (100%) for all database types

```
SELECT s.*
FROM stock s,
     (SELECT shelf, MAX(item_id) AS last_id FROM stock GROUP BY shelf) sub
WHERE s.shelf = sub.shelf
AND s.item_id = sub.last_id
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in postgres as written since it complains that a subquery can only return a single column. If we convert it to SQL-92 syntax of specifying the join in the `from` clause rather then in the `where` clause it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number` window function:

```
SELECT shelf, item_id, item_name
FORM   (SELECT shelf, item_id, item_name,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITOIN BY shelf ORDER BY item_id DESC) rn
        FROM   stock)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of obtaining the results and I have illustrated some in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d493a7). The methods suggested by @prdp @mureinik are some of the best methods to approach.

```
SELECT B.shelf,B.item_id,A.item_name
FROM stock A
JOIN (SELECT shelf, MAX(item_id) as item_id FROM stock GROUP BY shelf) B ON A.item_id=B.item_id AND A.shelf=B.shelf


SELECT A.shelf,A.item_id,A.item_name
FROM stock A
WHERE item_id = (SELECT  MAX(item_id) FROM stock B where A.shelf = B.shelf)
```